# Rename files to insert _ between StudlyCapsified words

Tags: files, scripting, rename

I've a music lib where files names are like `05WithoutWallsSpanishMixChillDeLucia.mp3` (no space between words BUT exist a capital letter at beginning of every word).

How do I detect this string form and insert a `_` between every lower case and upper case character in order to have this form: `05_Without_Walls_Spanish_Mix_Chill_De_Lucia.mp3`?

Comment: Does your system provide the perl-based `rename` (`prename`) command?

Comment: yes i've prename , i never used it before !

Comment: this programe can do what i'm looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `prename` (which may be `rename` on some systems)

```
prename -vn -- 's/(?=[[:upper:]])/_/g' *.mp3
```

will substitute an underscore before each uppercase character in every file in the current directory that has suffix `.mp3`

The `-n` option provides a dry-run: it won't actually modify filenames unless you remove the `n`

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for !

Comment: Be aware that it will insert an underscore before EVERY uppercase character - that may not be exactly what you want (for example if you have mp3 files whose names begin with an uppercase character rather than a digit)

Comment: yes i'm aware of that  :)